# Unable to open dataurl using utils.openUrl()

Tags: nativescript

For Nativescript, I created a pdf using `pdfmake` on the client side. Now using its `dataUrl`, I want to display it in a browser. But while trying to open it using `utils.openUrl(dataUrl)`, it gives error `Error in OpenURL`

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition)
  .getDataUrl((dataUrl) => {
      utils.openUrl(dataUrl);
  });
```

But if I paste dataUrl directly into browser address, it opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDataUrl(callback)` returns a base64 data link which can not be handled by `utils.openUrl(...)`. Moreover Android doesn't have the capability to open PDF in Browser.

The alternative is to write the PDF to a file and use [nativescript-share-file](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-share-file) for preview. This plugin gives user a list of options user could choose from to view / share the given file.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I was looking for.